# Excel PowerQuery / C# WebAPI OData, Retrieving old Service Reference

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-web-api, odata, powerquery

Having some strange behavior when trying to connect Excel Power Query to my OData web service.

When I started out building my web service my underlying data class (POCO) was called 'FilterSearchFacade'.  As development continued, I renamed the underlying data class to 'ReportSource'.

When I connect to the web service using a URL through a web browser, the correct 'ReportSource' object is returned.  However, when I connect with PowerQuery, it returns the following error:[image]

It's as if there's some data cache in Excel that is holding on to the old class definition?

I have tried...

*In Excel going to "Power Query" > "Recent Sources", deleting them all and restarting excel.

*Searching the entirety of all code in my WebAPI project for the class name 'FilterSearchFacade', there are none.

*Deleting the bin/obj folders from the WebAPI project, cleaning and    rebuilding.

When I go to the $metadata root of the project from the web browser,    it shows the correct class definition:

Debugging locally: `http://localhost:61023/api/PortlandDev/2/$metadata`

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
<edmx:DataServices>
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Sulzer.STAT.DataService">
<EntityType Name="ReportSource">
<Key>...
```

I'm stumped here.  The OData project has no references to the 'FilterSearchFacade' class but Excel is still trying to reference that type.  Any ideas as to additional items to look in to or how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it has stale data. You can try clearing the Power Query cache by going to Options | Global | Data Load and click on Clear Cache. You may also need to clear the cache in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, this works for me.  For anyone looking in the future, location of the clear cache button is on the 'Data' toolbar | 'New Query' dropdown | 'Query Options' | 'Global' | 'Data Load'